# ASP.NET Removing Querystring from friendly URL

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Hey I am trying to remove a querystring from a friendly URL i.e I have

`/who-we-are/our-people.html?linkidentifier=id&itemid=42`

And I want to change the above to

`/who-we-are/our-people.html`

How can I remove anything after the `.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest way to do it reliably is to use the `System.Uri` class:

```
string pathOnly = new Uri("http://whatever.com/who-we-are/our-people.html?linkidentifier=id&itemid=42").AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: How can i just replace the url in the address bar with `pathOnly`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do URL rewriting.

Here you can find more about this [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Request`'s `Path` property - this article should give you everything you need: [Making Sense of ASP.NET Paths](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths)